# Get Wordpress Category from Single Post

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm finishing up a WP theme, and I'm on the single.php template. I'm having some issues because I need to access the parent category that a post is in in order to display certain images and XML content.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. The following is the end url of a single post:

/andrew/leaf-art-2/

`/andrew/` is the category, and `leaf-art-2` is the single post. When I am on the single post, I am having trouble getting `single_cat_title();` to return the category that the current post is in. I am using `single_cat_title();` instead of `the_category();` because it displays the string value of the category which I then use to place a picture of the artist (whose category this is) on their posts. I don't have any use for the url, I just need the string with the category name.

Any good ways of doing this? I have been searching the Wordpress Codex and lots of forums, and haven't found any answers yet.

---

The following was my original post.

<del>I have set up a category called "artists" which when I run `single_cat_title("", false);` I can get the string value of the category and then use it to search for the appropriate artist image using XML.</del>

<del>This works fine on the category.php template page.</del>

<del>The problem is that when I'm actually inside of a single post that has the "artists" category, single_cat_title(); doesn't output any information to the page, thereby keeping me from accessing the XML data.</del>

<del>I need to, while in the "artists" > "sample" post, be able to get from WP the category.</del>

<del>P.S. the above category is one of many that is using this setup, which is why I can't hardcode it.</del>

Answer (score 68, accepted):

How about [get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)?

You can then do

```
$category = get_the_category();
$firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw this, but assumed that [0] would call from the first of all the categories, not the first of all the categories the post was posted in. Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote: If you have a custom taxonomy (not the default "category"), you can use [`get_the_terms();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

Comment: be aware that `$category[0]` will generate warnings if the post has no categories; it would be wise to check with `if(!empty($category)){$firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;}`

Answer (score 7):

For the lazy and the learning, to put it into your theme, Rfvgyhn's full code

```
<?php $category = get_the_category();
$firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name; echo $firstCategory;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get `category` names with `permalink` in `single` post without `loop`

```
the_category(',', '', get_the_ID())
```

If you want only the first one:

```
get_the_category(get_the_ID())[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="post_category">
        <?php $category = get_the_category();
             $allcategory = get_the_category(); 
        foreach ($allcategory as $category) {
        ?>
           <a class="btn"><?php echo $category->cat_name;; ?></a>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
 </div>
```